# Not working "serve" command for Vue js project

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

working with Laravel + Vue js. but when I try to start vue js using **npm run serve** command. it is en counting following error command in my cmd .

**npm ERR! Missing script: "serve"

npm ERR!

npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:

npm ERR!   npm run**

how could I fix this problem?

**package.json**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.24.0",
        "cross-env": "^7.0",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.39",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "vue": "^2.6.14",
        "vue-axios": "^3.3.7",
        "vue-router": "^3.5.2",
        "vue-sweetalert2": "^5.0.2"
    }
}
```

Comment: could you add your `package.json` in the question?

Comment: To run a certain script with ```npm``` run it needs to be in scripts inside your ```package.json```

Comment: @Amaarrockz please check my package.json

Comment: @MuhammadYasir please check my package.json

Comment: Yes if you see you don't have scripts for `serve`, that's the reason why its throwing that error

Comment: Check my Answer

Answer (score 1):

This is not only vue js app. you are using `vue` with `Laravel`

If you want to create production build you have to run `npm run prod`.
If you working local then you should use `npm run watch`. it will use hot reload so it will detect file changes and create complied filed.

**Note :  you have to add resourse js & css file to webpack.mix.js file and define the destination to store complied file in public folder.**

You don't have to use `npm run serve` because you are using vue js in laravel.

Comment: got following error **> development
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress
--hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watc
h"<br>

[webpack-cli] Error: Unknown option '--hide-modules'<br>
[webpack-cli] Run 'webpack --help' to see available commands and options**

Comment: what command you have used?

Comment: I suggest you to use `watch` for local development and `prod` for production build when you make your site live

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the below content inside the `package.json`, if not add it and then try running the commands

```
"scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    // other commands
  },
```

Edit:

If you are using `cmd` in windows.

Follow the below steps

1. Try deleting the node_modules folder and after that run `npm i` from the cmd.
2. Then try running `npm run serve` again and see if it works this time
3. if the above two steps don't work then install vue/cli service globally by running the command `npm install @vue/cli-service -g` and then follow step 1 and 2 sequentially

Comment: I got following error command **'vue-cli-service' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

Comment: may I run npm update command after put new codes here?

Comment: Check the edited answer

Comment: I did every steps with install vue cli but got following error messages **ERROR  Error: Cannot find module 'vue-template-compiler/package.json'**

Answer (score 0):

I did every steps and when i run npm run serve i got this:
PS C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> npm run serve
npm ERR! Missing script: "serve"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Make Users\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-01-23T15_13_24_934Z-debug-0.log

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33690636)